# How to save space between insde strings

Tags: javascript, string

Need to save space after joining as in the first line of code

```
var str = "PB 10 CV 2662"; 
str = str.split(" ") //[ 'PB', '10', 'CV', '2662' ]
str = str.join("") // 'PB10CV2662'
```

or in one line:

```
str = str.split(" ").join("")
```

Comment: As in a var not as in the result

Comment: `str.split(" ").join(" ");`. Just `join` them using a space instead of an empty string.

Comment: Just use join method in follow way : `str = str.split(" ").join(" ")`(using space inside join method)

Comment: If you need the spaces, why the split and join? What's the real underlying goal here? (More: [*What is the X/Y problem?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ehem ehem! Wrong meta link. I think you meant [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/364209). (**ID:66377** not **ID:6377**).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Thanks. My question is: How the heck did THAT happen? I copied it from my bookmarks, and my bookmark is correct. Must have accidentally hit the Del key while editing the comment...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I was wondering the same thing. o_O